# if the projection of $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ has (n-1) dim. measure zero, then the set $E$ has $n$-dim. measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich, at page 121, it is asked that

> Prove that if the projection of a bounded set $E\subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ onto a hyperplane $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ has (n-1)
>   dimensional measure zero, then the set $E$ itself has $n$-dimensional
>   measure zero.

I even cannot see the result intuitively, so I'm hoping you guys can help me to prove it, or give some hints about how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $E \subset P(E) \times [a,b]$, where $P$ is the projection and $a,b$ are some real numbers. This follows from the fact that $E$ is bounded. Therefore $0 \leq m_n(E) \leq (b-a) m_{n-1}(P(E))=0$. (Also, $E$ is Lebesgue measurable because it is contained in a known measurable set which has zero measure, and the Lebesgue measure is complete.)

Comment: Isn't $P(E)$ measurable since it has measure $0$? Do you need that $E$ is measurable? ($E$ is a subset of a measure $0$ set so it must be measurable with measure $0$)

Comment: That $E$ is measurable is a consequence of the calculation Ian did. You can see $\mathfrak{m}_n(E)$ as the outer measure of $E$, at a first moment.

Comment: @Levent Usually I prefer to avoid having to explicitly thinking about whether measures are complete or not by just assuming that all measures I want to write down make sense. But yes, the Lebesgue measure is complete so this is not necessary. Alternatively, you could think of all of these as being outer measures. The end result is the same. Still, I edited it a bit.